# Retrieving affected records through T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Following sample returns affected ROWCOUNT.  Is there a way to return affected IDENTITYs?

```
UPDATE HumanResources.Employee 
SET JobTitle = N'Executive'
WHERE NationalIDNumber = 123456789
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
PRINT 'Warning: No rows were updated';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE HumanResources.Employee 
SET JobTitle = N'Executive'
OUTPUT INSERTED.PrimaryKeyID
WHERE NationalIDNumber = 123456789
```

**Here I assumed Id name is PrimaryKeyID.**

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE HumanResources.Employee 
SET JobTitle = N'Executive'
OUTPUT INSERTED.YourIdentityColumn
WHERE NationalIDNumber = 123456789
```

[OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Comment: This won't work without prefixing `YourIdentityColumn` with `INSERTED `

Answer (score 0):

from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177564(v=sql.120).aspx

```
DELETE FROM dbo.table1
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO @MyTableVar
WHERE id = 4 OR id = 2;
```